# Exec Command not Working in PHP

Tags: php, iis-express

I am simply trying to run an executable file from a PHP script.  Seems simple enough but it just will not work for me. I have tried both of these methods:

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("Notepad.exe >> /err.txt");
```

and

```
exec("Notepad.exe >> /err.txt");
```

without success.  Nothing seems to happen, I step through my code and the lines execute but notepad does not open.  Err.txt is empty so there is no help there and I can't find an error anywhere.  I would think if it was a permissions issue I would get an error message, and other than that I'm not sure what the problem can be. It seems to find Notepad.exe ok because when I write Ntpad.exe I get an error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The script is running from a local IISExpress site.

Comment: Who is the PHP script running as?

Comment: On my mind, if service does not have interaction with the desktop checked - the window of started application will not be shown.

Comment: I don't necessarily need it to show up, Notepad was just for debugging the actual script I was to run looks like this:
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd C:\path\ffmpeg -i C:\path\video.mov video.mp4");
It doesn't seem to run as the .mp4 is not created but when I run the same script from the command line it works.

Comment: I'm fairly new to PHP debug methods, is there a way I can debug this issue better?  the script isn't executing I know this much because no converted file is returned, but from a php perspective it doesn't return any error or anything period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration I figured out the answer, thanks to Cheery for letting my know that Notepad would never show up without desktop interaction I would have been there for a while trying to figure out why it wasn't working.  There was a few problems with my original script...

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd C:\Test\ffmpeg -i C:\Test\ferrisglennnews.mov video.webm");
```

1. double slashes are needed
2. cmd must be removed
3. not having a directory puts the output in the default cmd directory not where the source file is so I   was looking in the wrong place for the output

Thus this is the script the produced the desired results was...

```
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\\Test\\ffmpeg -i C:\\Test\\ferrisglennnews.mov C:\\Test\\video.webm");
```

Thanks for those who helped out and who help out in forum period, you saved so many people soooo much time!